# R - SQL query only takes 1000 Arguments

Tags: r

I want to perform a database query in SQL in my script. However, the query is too large because SQL only takes 1000 arguments. Now I have tinkered with the modulo operator but wonder if there is not a more elegant approach that also works when the amount of data increases.

Thanks in advance

```
modulo <- length(ticker_selected) + (1000 - length(ticker_selected) %% 1000)
temp <- list()
for(x in 1:(modulo/1000)) {try(
  temp[x] <- toString(sprintf("'%s'",(ticker_selected)[(length(ticker_selected)-(x-1)*999):(length(ticker_selected) - (x*999))]))
  , silent = TRUE)}
temp[x] <- toString(sprintf("'%s'",(ticker_selected)[1:((length(ticker_selected)%%999))]))
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you are trying to produce a query string with no more than 1000 tickers to select? You _could_ insert a temp table with the 1000 or more tickers, then inner-join against it from your real tables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the code below?

1. To create a string in chunks of `ticker_selected`, define a chunk size;
2. the number of passes through `ticker_selected` is the integer quotient of its length by that size;
3. and there will be a remaining/modulo left to read at the end.

First loop through each pass then what's left. I find the code more readable.
And, not counting with 0 and 1, **the only hard-coded constant is right at its beginning.**

```
chunk_size <- 1000L
passes <- length(ticker_selected) %/% chunk_size
remaining <- length(ticker_selected) %% chunk_size
temp <- vector("list", length = passes + (remaining != 0))
start <- 1L

for(i in seq_len(passes)) {
  current <- ticker_selected[start:(start + chunk_size - 1L)]
  current <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", current))
  start <- start + chunk_size
  temp[i] <- current
}
if(remaining != 0) {
  current <- ticker_selected[start:length(ticker_selected)]
  current <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", current))
  temp[length(temp)] <- current
}
```

---

## Edit

Answering to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73190244/r-sql-query-only-takes-1000-arguments/73190543?noredirect=1#comment131487363_73190543)  by user [Abe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10206412/abe), I believe the following solves the problem.

1. Substitute `dataframe$variable` for `tickers_selected`;
2. Run the queries in a `lapply` loop returning a results list;
3. `rbind` the results.

```
query_results_list <- lapply(temp, \(x) {
  s <- sprintf("SELECT var1, var2 FROM database WHERE identifier IN ( %s ) ", x)
  DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, s)
})

# fast
result <- data.table::rbindlist(query_results_list)

# slow but base R
result <- do.call(rbind, query_results_list)
```

Comment: Hi there! I came across this solution and am hoping it my solve a problem for me. I'm trying to pass a column from a data frame in my environment to the WHERE clause of a SQL query and am hitting the maximum query text length due to the number of elements in the column. Is this an appropriate solution for that problem? If so, it isn't clear to me from the answer here where the SQL query (e.g. ```DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, sprintf("SELECT var1, var2 FROM database WHERE identifier IN ( %s ) ",paste(dataframe$variable, collapse = ',')))```) goes. Can you provide some guidance?

Comment: @Abe See if the edit solves the problem.